# What would cause an IIS6 website to be unavailable remotely randomly for a few minutes at a time?

Tags: windows-server-2003, web-server, iis-6, website

Website is served by iis6 on windows server 2003.  Never saw this problem once for months in beta.  We made the new site live yesterday - its getting more traffic than in beta but not that much - resource utilization on the server and speed are fine.

Today the site has been unavailable remotely a few (4?) times for a few minutes at a time.  If you visit any page on the site - nothing is ever returned and eventually the request times out.  While this is happening - I can connect to the server via remote desktop and the site loads fine from the live url when running a browser on the server locally.  Other websites on the server continiue to function fine the entire time (using the same instance of iis, different app pools).  Other computers on the same network can't access the website either.

Other than not serving content - the server seems to behave normally - scheduled jobs in our custom job system continue to run, etc.  We've looked at the iis logs quickly and we don't see any traffic out of the ordinary - no traffic spikes, etc.

Any ideas?  Thanks,
Shane

Answer (score 0):

Anything strange in Application and System Windows logs?

Is this an ASP or ASP.NET web site (or even anything else)?

What happens if you ask a static HTML page, or an image?

Answer (score 0):

Is it anything to do with the DNS record for this domain? Is the record registered/hosted somewhere different to your other sites, and it's this that fails, not the server?

Comment: Also try http://www.watchmouse.com/en/checkit.php or similar service - is it just your network that's unable to see the server?